# Limit content width in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using Beamer (Madrid theme) with a logo added to the right lower corner of each frame using the following:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south east, yshift=.5cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]
{logo.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Now text overlaps with the logo. Is there a way to control the width of slide content accordingly or automatically hide the logo when overflow happens?
[image: sample]

Comment: You could increase the right margin using \geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\setbeamersize{text margin right=1.75cm}` to increase the right margin a bit to leave enough room for your logo

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south east, yshift=.5cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\setbeamersize{text margin right=1.75cm}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```